# Visual Studio 2013 always hangs registering for layout, must renew dev license every day, every project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm an experienced dev, but working with Windows code for the first time. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and EVERY time I open or create a new project and try to build/run Visual Studio hangs at "Registering the application to run from layout..."

I found a SO post that said this was related to my Developer License and I just needed to renew it. I renewed it, but it didn't work. So, I restarted VS and it still didn't work, so I rebooted Windows, and then FINALLY it worked.

I thought it was a one time issue, but EVERY DAY and EVERY PROJECT/SOLUTION that I open and try to run hangs and I have to renew my license and reboot my computer. What the hell? What is going wrong?

EDIT: I don't know what has changed, but thankfully, I only have to renew my license whenever I open a new project. I don't have to renew every day, but if I create any new project or download any new sample code project, I still need to get a new license. It doesn't make sense, but at least it's not AS horrible.

Comment: If you search on Google for "Registering the application to run from layout" there are some results which suggest it could be a file systems permissions issue.

Comment: I'm dealing with a project directory that doesn't move and I'm not changing. It works all day, but then the next morning is no good.

Answer (score 0):

If you have antivirus software installed, see if temporarily disabling it makes a difference. In my case Avast slowed most VS2013 operations to a crawl, even though I added the directories as exceptions.

Comment: I checked and I'm not running any antivirus. :/